# Ratio of an increasing monotonic function and its integral is infinity

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Inspired by the fact that for functions at the form: $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^\alpha}$ where $\alpha \ge 1$, the intgeral: $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx$ diverges to $\infty$ , and the ratio: $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ approaches $-\infty$ as $x$ approaches zero (from the right), I developed the following hypothesis:
let $f: [0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous monotonic function such that $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx = \infty$, then $\lim_{x\to 1^{-}} \frac{f(x)}{\int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt} = \infty$, however I was unable to solve this problem completely, and wanted to ask for some help with it, here's what I got so far:
I know that if I define: $g(x) = \ln(\int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt)$, then: $g'(x) = \frac{f(x)}{\int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt}$, meaning the desired ratio is unbounded, I also know that if I define: $f(x) = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}|\sin(\frac{1}{1-x})|$, then the desired limit does not exist, meaning I have to use the fact that $f(x)$ is monotonic, somehow in the proof, my guess, is that it implies  that the ratio is also montonic (because that also when happens with $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^\alpha}$), or at least that the ratio is monotonic from some point, and from there, the claim is obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $f$ is positive and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 1^-} f(x) = +\infty$. Fix some $\varepsilon > 0$ then
$$
\frac{f(x)}{\int_0^{x}f(t)\, dt} = \frac{f(x)}{\int_0^{1 - \varepsilon}f(t)\, dt + \int_{1 - \varepsilon}^xf(t)\, dt}\ge \frac{f(x)}{\int_0^{1 - \varepsilon}f(t)\, dt + \varepsilon f(x)},
$$
hence we have
$$
\liminf_{x\to 1^-}\frac{f(x)}{\int_0^{x}f(t)\, dt}\ge \liminf_{x\to 1^-}\frac{f(x)}{\int_0^{1 - \varepsilon}f(t)\, dt + \varepsilon f(x)} = \frac{1}{\varepsilon}.
$$
The conjecture follows.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really struggled with this problem, I just a have a couple of small questions for clarification: 1) don't you also require that $1-\epsilon < x$?. 2) the reason you used lim inf instead of a regular limit was to ensure existence?

Comment: Yes, you are right the inequality $x > 1-\varepsilon$ is essential, it can be assumed since $x$ tend to $1$. And yes, the liminf is for the existence

Comment: Great, thanks a lot, you really helped.